# Indicator Applet: How to get rid of the clock?

Tags: applet, indicator, clock

There are currently 2 clocks on my panel: one in the "Indicator Applet" and one in the "Clock".  The one in the "Indicator Applet" is redundant and isn't as good as the "Clock".

Does anyone know how to get rid of the clock in the "Indicator Applet"?

Comment: Do you mean the calendar applet? I'm not aware of a clock in the Indicator Applet.

Comment: Do you use Gnome or KDE?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must have somehow installed the new, under development Ubuntu clock. Go into Synaptic, and remove the package `indicator-datetime`. That should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I wonder when I installed that though.  Maybe it came with another package.

Comment: Did you install Unity? Unity uses it, and so installs the package on install.

Comment: is it possible to install clock as an indicator-applet? the indicator-datetime is too minimal.